# How can I share a TFS task board outside of TFS?

Tags: tfs

It's pretty straight forward. We have a local TFS installation and lots of people (including stakeholders) are outside our local office. As it stands, for me to be able to allow stakeholders to see the task board I have to add them to our local AD (AAD is not sufficient) and then add permissions to TFS. While this is understandably a secure way of doing it, I would hope there would have to be a way to just simply "share" a task board. Maybe a Link or iframe on a local website. Anything ideas are welcome.

I have tried to extend TFS by using Aha, Jira and solutions like that, but even those cannot simply take said task board and display it over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There are no public projects and no anonymous access.

VSTS has public projects in preview, but you'd have to migrate from TFS to VSTS in order to make use of that.